# Java RMI and remote file access

Tags: java, rmi

I'm just starting to learn Java's RMI, and believe I understand the process, client sends method requests and params, server does computation and sends return result back.

However does the server perform everything within the method locally?

Specifically, if a file is read in the method, am I correct in thinking this is performed by the server?

If this is the case is there any way for the method to specifically access resources from the client (such as the client's System.out?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If by locally, you mean on the server (virtual) machine, the answer is yes.
2. Yes.
3. No, only values explicitly passed as arguments to the remote method are accessible. And you can only pass objects which are `Serializable`, and streams typically aren't.

Having said that, a client can also act as a server, exporting its own remote objects, which can be passed to the (other) server, which can then use that remote object to call the client back.

Comment: Okay thank you :) Thinking about it, if I had a RMI method taking an output stream, and the client gave System.out as the argument could the server perform write operations, println() etc on the clients output stream?

Comment: @akd5446 No, you can't pass any output stream, because most output streams aren't serializable (look for the "All implemented interfaces" section of their javadocs). Another problem with this approach is that parameter passing is one way only, even if you could pass a stream, the client wouldn't see the changes. What I suggest is to have your method return a `byte []` or simply a `String`, which you write into on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I say yes, your'e correct. By definition the (remote)method runs on the server side. The client just holds a fake object (proxy or stub) that makes the connection to the server, passes the arguments and gets the return value for you.

Think about the client and server running in different machines, there's no way to server knows anything about the client's resources, unless the client acts itself as a server.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rmiio](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/) to easily stream data over rmi.  that said i highly doubt you would want to do that with System.out.